# NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When I compile my code, I get the following:

```
Display ommitted hash table: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hash.display_hash_table(Hash.java:268)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:20)
```

Here are the relevant portions of code:

```
public void display_hash_table() 
{
    System.out.println("Display ommitted hash table: ");

    pw.append("Display ommitted hash table: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + "\t" + table[i].getData());

        pw.append(String.valueOf(i) + "\t" + table[i].getData() + "\n");

    }

    System.out.println("The total number of probes is: " + String.valueOf(this.count_probe) +     "\n");

    pw.append("The total number of probes is: " + String.valueOf(this.count_probe) + "\n");

}
```

and

```
    omitted_words.display_hash_table();
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could possibly be my error?  Thank you!

Comment: On line 268 of your Hash class you try to access an object, that is null. Either it is pw or table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` being null is the most likely cause of your exception.

Comment: me being a moron was the cause actually.  I needed to include the omitted.txt file, with the omitted words, in the project folder.  I  figured it out and the program works as expected now.